# Can not pass variable on function using jQuery .then()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery loading a json, and I am using .then() notation to run a function doThis() when the json is ready. However, if I pass a variable on doThis(), it returns 'undefined'.

I figured out this much: In my application the jQuery gets run on mouse click, and when passing a variable, it does run on second mouse click. Seems like the json gets loaded, but jQuery does not wait for the json to finish loading if I pass a variable.

This works:

```
$.getJSON('/endpoint/', function(data) {
  data = data
})
  .then(doThis)
```

This does not work even with no variable in the parenthesis:

```
$.getJSON('/endpoint/', function(data) {
  data = data
})
  .then(doThis())
```

I am sure this has something to do with the architecture of JavaScript. Would be awesome if someone could enlighten me a little.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the `then()` expects a callback.  Unless `doThis()` returns a function, you're not giving it a callback in the second instance.

Comment: You need `.then(function () { doThis(someValue); });`

Comment: Could also use `bind()`

Comment: It's actually: `.then(function (data) { doThis(data, someOtherValue); });` (or: `then(doThis.bind(this, data))`)

Comment: That solved it, thanks!